# How to prevent my theorems from breaking off at a pagebreak?

Tags: page-breaking, theorems, mdframed

I styled the theorems in my document a bit, using the `mdframed` package. I'm glad with the result, but the frame sometimes breaks off incorrectly. I've created a sample to show you what's going wrong.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\textheight 22.4cm
\parskip 12pt
\definecolor{lichtgrijs}{gray}{0.95}
\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{ %
    backgroundcolor=lichtgrijs, %
    linewidth=0pt, %
    innertopmargin=10pt, %
    innerbottommargin=10pt %
}

\newmdtheoremenv[style=mystyle]{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \begin{theorem}
        This is my theorem.
        \vspace{-15pt}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item It breaks of ugly.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, a gray banner from the theorem is shown on the second page. Obviously, that's not very desirable.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `nobreak=true` to your definition of `mystyle:

```
\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{ %
    backgroundcolor=lichtgrijs, %
    linewidth=0pt, %
    innertopmargin=10pt, %
    innerbottommargin=10pt,%
    nobreak=true% prevent page breaks in the middle of mystyle
}
```

With this your theorem stays on the bottom of the first page:

[image]

Comment: For anyone searching, this approach works for the `kaobook` template. In `kaotheorems.sty`, add this parameter to `\mdfdefinestyle{mdfkao}{... }`.